# How to change existing, installed module code

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2, I have tried to change code for an existing, intalled module from app/code but it's not showing as changed in the browser. What steps are need to follow to apply the changes in live?

Can you please help me with the proper steps?

Comment: Welcome to SFO.  It's helpful if you explain a bit more in detail about what you have already tried.

Comment: I have tried to change the code within the app/code module files and upload the site in server. But it changes doesn't effect in browser module page. What steps are required to apply the change?

Answer (score 0):

If the change includes version, you have to do setup upgrade to get reflected. If 'minify and merge of JS/CSS' is enabled, then you have to run deploy command to get reflected. Caching system have to be considered

1. php bin/magento setup:upgrade
2. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
3. php bin/magento cache:clean